# Correct use of tense with "avoir des nouvelles de [qch]"

Tags: grammaire

If I want to say "I haven't heard from him for a long time", which of the following is appropriate and why:

> je n'ai pas de nouvelles de lui depuis longtemps
> je n'ai pas eu de nouvelles de lui depuis longtemps

Also, would it be possible to say either of these:

> Je n'ai pas de ses nouvelles depuis longtemps
> Je n'ai pas eu de ses nouvelles depuis longtemps

Thanks!

Comment: *de ses nouvelles* is the most probably the best but it might depend on context - what has been said before?  Same for the choice of tense, one could be better than the other according to context.

Comment: *Ça fait un bail que j'ai pas eu de ses nouvelles !*

Comment: I can't see a reason to choose one over another other than personal preference. They're all appropriate and natural.

Comment: The first could be written best : je n’ai pas de nouvelles venant de lui depuis longtemps. In the second form, ´eu de des nouvelles’ est plus correct.

Answer (score 1):

**AVOIR EU vs AVOIR:**

> **avoir eu** ... depuis longtemps

is probably better grammatically than

> **avoir** ... depuis longtemps

but both sound alright in spoken form.

**SES vs DES...DE LUI:**

> avoir eu de **ses** nouvelles

may be preferred to

> avoir eu **des** nouvelles **de lui**

because it is quicker to say, but both are alright grammatically and they mean the same, even if *avoir eu **des** nouvelles **de lui*** allows someone to emphasize that it is from *him* if the word *lui* is stressed.